# Why the numbers 6 and 8 not selected when indexing this numpy array?

Tags: numpy, indexing

In the below code why the numbers 6 and 8 not selected?

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4) \
b1 = np.array([False, True, True]) \
b2 = np.array([True, False, True, False])

a[b1,b2]
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is (roughly) the following:

1. Numpy looks for the indices of the `True`- Entries in `b1`and `b2`.
   This is similar to

```
idx1 = np.where(b1)    # [1,2]
idx2 = np.where(b2)    # [0,2]
```

2. Numpy iterates over all elements in `idx1` and `idx2` in parallel. For this, it is important, that both list have the same length, i.e. `b1` and `b2` have the same number of `True`values (try it with `b2 = np.array([True, False, True, True])` and your code will brake).

The following code demonstrates, what happens and prints the elements of `a[b1,b2]`:

```
for i in range(len(idx1)):
    u = idx1[i]
    v = idx2[i]
    print(a[u,v])
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your numpy selector is to use

```py
a[b1][:, b2]
```

The actual reason it didn't show 6 and 8 was because the two arrays you selected didn't change any of their shapes but made pairs of `(x, y)` instead. `a[b1]` will result in the shape changing from `(3, 4)` to `(2, 4)`. Let's call this result `x`. Now you want to slice along the other axis using b2. Doing `x[:, b2]` will slice it another time at the other axis, changing the shape from `(2, 4)` to `(2, 2)`.

In other words, the selector that you used paired `b1` and `b2`. The pairs that were in different lists which are `[1, 2]` and `[0, 2]` to `[1, 0]` and `[2, 2]`. If you put both lists together, it can also be understood as transposing the selecting matrix from

```py
[[1 2]
 [0 2]]
```

into

```py
[[1 0]
 [2 2]]
```